# Making a function sensitive for vector input

Tags: matlab

This is for my course in numerical methods. I am trying very hard to understand MATLAB and its syntax but I am 100% self-taught, so please bear with me if my attempts seem ridiculous.

I have written this very easy function to approximate the number e

```
function e= calcEulerLimit(n)
e = (1 + 1./n).^n;
end
```

This is the 'basic' definition of the number e using a limit n to infinity approach. For MATLAB I defined the following vector (when I am talking about n in the latter, I am always referring to this vector `n`)

```
n=[1:1:10]=[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ]
```

and the output works just fine as I expected, it is sensitive towards the vector `n` input when I call my function in MATLAB.

```
>> calcEulerlimit(n)

ans =

    2.0000    2.2500    2.3704    2.4414    2.4883    2.5216    2.5465    2.5658    2.5812    2.5937
```

---

Now I want to do the exact same as above with a Taylor Approach, using the infinite summation formula to describe e, here is where I am stuck, the following simple code works:

```
function e = calcEulerSum(n)
e=1;                % base-case, start variable
for i=1:1:n       % for loop with step size one
    e=e+1/factorial(i)
end
end
```

but this input, of course, does not work when I want to enter a vector such as `n` that computes through all variables.

I tried something along the line with another for loop, and a while loop, but the while loop seems to never terminate:

```
function e = calcEulerSum3(n)
while n
e=1;
e = e + 1./cumprod(n);
end
end
```

Using `cumprod(n)` to get the factorial value of each column element of my vector `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to vectorize your function. Your solution for scalars works so let's look at what it's doing as `i` is incremented:

```
       e0 = 1;
i = 1: e(1) = e0 + 1/factorial(1)
i = 2: e(2) = e(1) + 1/factorial(2) = e0 + 1/factorial(1) + 1/factorial(2)
                                    = e0 + sum(1./factorial(1:2))
i = 3: e(3) = e(2) + 1/factorial(3) = ...
                                    = e0 + sum(1./factorial(1:3))
    ...
i = n: e(n) = e(n-1) + 1/factorial(n) = e0 + 1/factorial(1) + ... + 1/factorial(n)
                                      = e0 + sum(1./factorial(1:n))
```

So can you come up with a general expression to calculate the vector `e` given `n`? The [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) function will come in handy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will read about the cumsum, 
So far I am at

for i=n, e=1, e= e + 1./factorial(n); 

which seemed clear to me, but the output I get is 2, 1.5, 1.1667, 1.0417

 so it seems like it 'works' besides the addition part.

Comment: @Spaced: `n` is a vector. If you're using a `for` loop you're probably going to need to index into it: `n(i)`. And you're probably also going to need to save the outputs in a vector: `e(i)`.

Comment: See my pseudo-code example above. The output `e` is going to be a vector, right? Can you calculate the first element of `e`? Given the first element, can you now calculate the second (`i=2`)? And so on... You can do this in a `for` loop and then you might see the how all of it can implemented in just one line of code using `cumsum`.

Comment: The base case is 1, the first is 2, the second 2.5 and this way it converges to e. To be honest, I couldn't see just from your code that e was going to be a vector, but I can take that. I can see that you're introducing a recursive definition first and then in the last line you say that that it is the base element plus the sums of all the 1/k! terms, which is mathematically indeed correct. 

So for instance e=1; e= e+ sum(1./factorial(1:10)) would lead to the correct answer of 2.7183, however is it possible to tell Matlab to output every single iteration separately ?

Comment: for instance, when I compute the function (without a for loop) like this e=1; e= e + sum(1./factorial(1:n)) where n is still my defined vector (as in the problem above stated n= 1:10) then the output will simply be 2. If I instead enter e = e + sum(1./factorial(n)), I get the correct result 2.718, but I want my output to be as in the example above:
2, 2.5, 2.568 and so on.

Comment: @Spaced: Yes. You need to index into `e`. You can't create it all at once when implementing a recursive loop as you've recognized. E.g., `e(i) = e(i-1)+1/factorial(i);`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and helpful explanation @horchler, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`for i=whatsoever,statement(i);end` executes the statement on every element of `whatsoever`. If it is a single number, then on this one, if it is a vector/array, then on every element of it.

`1:1:n` creates an array of integers from `1` to `n` on the spot (`1:n` would do, too). If `n` already is a vector with the elements you want to iterate over, you can use it directly: `for i=n`.

However, why did you use the dotted versions of operations in your first and third code block, but not your second? Because you read about MATLAB's vectorization? Then you seem to be on the right track, but remember that the point vectorization is to get rid of an explicit loop entirely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation @arne.b
I am reading through every manual of Matlab that I can find online and in the 2nd example I am dividing by factorial(i), which will always be a number. 

In the third example however, I would divide through by a vector and I have read that in this case I would have to use ./ to specify an element-wise division. The output does work, however it is not correct. I will try to understand it better.

Comment: @horchler How about "reduce the number of explicit loops"? At least, if there was a `for` loop before, and a `while` loop doing the same afterwards, there was no vectorization. :-)

Comment: @arne.b: Your edited version is much better (more precise/careful). I've voted this up for your explanations of how `for` loops work with vectors.

Answer (score -1):

```
function e = calcEulerSum(n)
e=nan(1,length(n));                % initialize to nan
for j=1:length(n)                % for each element in the input
    e(j)=sum(1./factorial(0:n(j))); %each entry is computed in this step, one at a time
end
```

In this code, each approximation has been vectorized, but I don't see an easy way to vectorize the entire program. There is also no error checking, like making sure the elements of n are non-negative integers, or that n is a vector and not an array.

In the original example, the while never terminates because n never changes.

This should be enough to help get you started.

Cheers!